# Finding number of methods used in a java program after selecting the file

Tags: java, methods, count

Are there any specific methods or functions to calculate the number of methods and not the constructors in java?

Very important, please share if you know something.

Comment: Try using Reflection.  Also, do you want static methods?

Comment: number of methods in a class?

Comment: Yes, its kind of weird but I really want to know.. Sri. U

Comment: Actually I have never used reflection API

Comment: If it is very important, pay money to get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Method[] declaredMethods = YourClass.class.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method : declaredMethods) {
    System.out.println(method.getName());
}
```